# How do I convert a text file into a list then sort it with Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.x

I have a text file with the following lyrics:

> 'First verse Im off till I'm off the island
>   i'm riding like autoban on autopilot
>   before I touch dirt I deal you all with kindness
>   my natual persona much worse'

I want to convert it to a list, then sort it alphabetically, but what I keep getting is: `[[First', 'verse', 'Im', 'off', 'till, "I'm", 'off' , 'the', 'island'] [then it prints the third line], [then the second line], [then the fourth line]]`

and then it puts it into a list within a list `[[ text, text..., ]]`

How do I print it so it prints in order in one list and is sorted in
alphabetical order using python code?  Here is what I have so far:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")  #prompts user for .txt file
fhand = open(fname)     #reads file
NewList =  []    #creating new list to append to
for line in fhand:    #for the lines in the text file, read them
    line.rstrip()   # strip the white space
    words = line.split()   #split the txt file into string words

    for word in words:      #for every word in txt file
        if words not in NewList:  #if not in the NewList
                NewList.append(words) #then appended words to Newlist 

                NewList.sort()    #sort it alphabetically

print NewList   #then print the sorted list
```

Comment: You probably want to add a tag for language you are using (Python?)

Comment: CamelCase should not be used in variable names in Python.

Comment: do you want to get rid of the repeated words when putting them in the list such as `I'm`

Comment: I think you want `NewList.extend(words)` instead of `NewList.append(words)`, if I understand you correctly. `extend` adds all the elements in the argument list to the existing list, where `append` adds the argument list itself to the existing list...

Comment: Yes, I also want to get rid of duplicate words....

Answer (score 2):

It's possible in a single line!

```
sorted(open('file.txt').readlines())
```

or, if you want it to be printed like a single file

```
print "".join(sorted(open('file.txt').readlines()))
```

Comment: Where's the Enter file name: bit?

Comment: Even if a one-liner is cool, you should use the `with` statement to close the file properly.

Comment: Thank you so far for the responses.  Well I want to keep it in a list bracket and sort it alphabetically so the output I desire is ['First', 'Im', 'I'm', 'island', 'off'. 'off', 'the', 'till', 'verse',....] and so on for the rest of the lines, all in one bracket--list.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a set to remove duplicate words and then sort it to a list

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname ,"r") as f:
    l = sorted(set([word for line in f for word in line.split()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Python 3**

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
newlist=[]
for line in fh:
    lst+=line.split()
for item in lst:
    if item not in newlist:
        newlist.append(item)
newlist.sort()
print(newlist)
```

*you're welcome*

Answer (score 0):

```
#For the second for loop, using continue will skip the already present word 
#in the list and go to the top of the loop for a new iteration.

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
handler = open(fname)
lst = list()
alst = list()

for line1 in handler :
    line1.rstrip()
    lst += line1.split()

for i in lst:
    if i not in alst:
        alst.append(i)
    else:
        continue
alst.sort()
print(alst)
```

Comment: @Tyler helpful ?